# Azure ApplicationInsights "Failures" is not reporting Exceptions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am attempting to implement Snapshot Debugger in MS Azure for a Function App, but the Failure tab in Application Insights displays only a fraction of the Exceptions thrown by the application.

As you can see in the two screenshots below, the Function App has run almost 300,000 times since January and has only registered 19 Exceptions in the Failures tab. Looking in Transaction Search tab appears to display each exception twice.

In reality, exceptions are thrown daily. These exceptions are recording in Transaction Search as "Errors" or sometimes "Traces"

Why would these exceptions not be showing up in the Failures tab or in Transaction Search as exceptions? Snapshot Debugger is not working on exceptions that are not labeled as such.

[image: Azure Application Insights Failures Tab]
[image: Azure Application Insights Transaction Search Tab]

Answer (score 0):

> As per the limitation according to this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/snapshot-debugger/snapshot-debugger#data-retention) Data from snapshot debugger is only stored for 15 Days thus not all exceptions are visible in your Applications Insights.

I tried configuring Snapshot debugger like below:-

**My Transaction search:-**

[image]

> As a workaround you can store Azure Function application logs in Storage account or Log analytics workspace by referring this [Document1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitor-log-analytics?tabs=csharp) and directly monitor function execution by referring [Document2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring#)